# Getting unexpected results form If expressions

Tags: function-construction, programming, evaluation, conditional

I'm mystified by this:

```
g[a_, b_, c_] := 
  Module[{d}, 
    d = If[(b < 1), b, b + 1]; 
    If[a < b, d = 0.]; 
    d*c]
g[a, 20, 40]
```

> `840`

I expected to see an output involving symbolic argument *a* !?? 
Now I change the second *If* so that *d* is set as returned by *If*, rather than by above's *If* argument statement, and now things work as expected:

```
g[a_, b_, c_] := 
  Module[{d}, 
    d = If[(b < 1), b, b + 1]; 
    d = If[a < b, 0., d]; 
    d*c]
g[a, 20, 40]
```

> `40 If[a < 20, 0., d$132874]`

Just for a bit more evidence, here is a 3rd casting, which also behaves as expected, although evaluation differs as expected:

```
g[a_, b_, c_] := 
  Module[{}, 
    If[(b < 1), b, b + 1]*If[a < b, 0., 1.]*c]
g[a, 20, 40]
```

> `840 If[a < 20, 0., 1.]`

How does one explain the result of the first expression form?

Comment: `I expected to see an output involving symbolic argument a !??` why? Also note that since `a` is a symbol, then `If[a < b, d = 0.]` does nothing since you do not have 3rd argument to `If`.  Check the third argument to `If` in help for more info.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is simple. In

```
g[a_, b_, c_] :=
  Module[{d},
    d = If[(b < 1), b, b + 1];
    If[a < b, d = 0.];
    d*c]
g[a, 20, 40]
```

the 1st line of the body of the module sets `d` to 21. The 2nd line can not be evaluated since the argument symbol `a` is not bound to a number, so it is left unevaluated and has no effect on `d`. The 3rd line, therefore, evaluates to 21 * 40, so 840 is returned.